# In complex analysis $f(\partial K) = \partial f(K)$ always for for compact $K$ and holomorphic $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

For a compact set $K \subset \Bbb{C}$ under the standard metric, does it hold that if $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on $K$, that $f(\partial K) = \partial f(K)$? If not, does $f(\partial K) \supset \partial f(K)$ hold? (here $\partial S:=\overline{S}\setminus \textrm{int}(S)$ denotes the boundary of $S$)

Comment: I think the answer is yes. $f( \partial K) = \partial f(K)$. That would follow intuitively from the fact that holomorphic functions map open sets to open sets and by continuity the boundry will then be mapped to the boundry of the image, but I would like to see a formal proof.

Comment: You mean holomorphic on an open set containing $K$?

Comment: @Thorgott: That's the usual definiition of holomorphic. But actually it suffices for the inclusion $\partial f(K)\subseteq f(\partial K)$ that $f$ is continuous on $K$ and holomorphic in the interior of $K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1. To prove $\partial f(K)\subseteq f(\partial K)$ use that $f(K)$ is closed and apply the invariance of domain theorem.
2. To see that the converse inclusion fails, consider $f(z)=z^2$ and the intersection of the closed unit disc with the closed upper half plane.